# Ioredis: ENOTFOUND when application running inside docker

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, ioredis, turborepo

I have a NodeJS/Typescript mono-repository powered by Turborepo in which I have multiple micro-services located in the `apps` folder. These micro-services communicate with each other through queues using `BullMQ` which uses Redis through the `ioredis` package. My Redis instance is public and hosted on redislabs.com.

My applications works fine in development and after compilation (using `tsc` to go from TS to JS), so using `npm run dev` and `npm run start`.

The application code to connect to my instance is the following:

```
const redis = new Redis({
  host: environment.QUEUE_REDIS_HOST, 
  port: environment.QUEUE_REDIS_PORT,
  username: environment.QUEUE_REDIS_USERNAME,
  password: environment.QUEUE_REDIS_PASSWORD,
  family: 6,
}),
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM  node:lts AS builder

WORKDIR /app
RUN yarn global add turbo
COPY . .
RUN turbo prune --scope=worker-notifications --docker

FROM node:lts AS installer

WORKDIR /app

COPY .gitignore .gitignore
COPY --from=builder /app/out/json/ .
RUN yarn install

COPY --from=builder /app/out/full/ .
COPY turbo.json turbo.json
RUN yarn turbo run build --filter=worker-notifications...

FROM  node:lts AS runner

WORKDIR /app

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nodejs
USER nodejs

COPY --from=installer /app .

CMD node apps/worker-notifications/dist/index.js
```

When running these application with Docker (using `docker run`), `ioredis` throws the following exception:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND xxx.cloud.redislabs.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:108:26) {
  errno: -3007,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'xxx.cloud.redislabs.com'
}
```

From the error message above, it seems to be a network issue with the application running inside the container not able to find the remote Redis instance ? Has anyone ever encountered such issue with `ioredis` and knows what I could be doing wrong here ?

Please note that I am certain this is not related to environment variables, spelling error in the instance URL, ... as these get validated by the application before the error is thrown.

Thank you very much for your help !